# Taking incremental backups of SQL Server 2008 Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup

We are building an ASP.NET application (with C#.net as language) and will be hosting on Windows Server 2003 Operating System with SQL Server 2008 as database.

We are planning to take the incremental database backups to a disk and use them to restore whenever there is a necessity.

So would you please guide me on this, if you have an idea?

If would be great if you could also provide a reference document or web references (If needed).

Answer (score 5):

The books online are a vital part of MS SQL Server with plenty of theory and examples.

The part about backing up in general  : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187048.aspx

The difference between the different forms of backup : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175477%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by Peter, read the SQL Books, you’re looking for something along the lines of:

```
BACKUP DATABASE ‘yourdbname’ TO DISK = ‘path+bak_name’;
```

Or something very similar (if you’re backing up to a drive, that is).

In my experience, that’s the best way for “portability” and easy restore if you know the path and filename of a backup.

But you’ll have to create a SQLserver helper class to control all these operations for you in an easy and abstract way.

Answer (score 0):

BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName  WITH DIFFERENTIAL